# Is Git's stashing mechanism essentially creating commit and then cherry-picking it?

Tags: git, git-stash

I've made changes in my working directory and then run `git stash`. In my `.dir/refs` directory I've got a new reference called `stash`, which is a pointer to the object with hash `2d05be16dcd0828c84d63f1e07ee78a2a28b3deb`. I've checked the type of the object and it's `commit`:

```
$ git cat-file -t 2d05be16dcd0828c84d63f1e07ee78a2a28b3deb
commit
```

So it seems that stashing indeed creates a commit. So when I unstash it, is it equivalent to cherry-picking it?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021591/why-wip-and-index-commit-listed-on-develop-after-stash/26022071#26022071

Comment: This as well https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/git-stash-pop-considered-harmful/

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that git probably uses `git read-tree` to apply the changes of the stash commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, but it's similar. Applying stashed changes modifies the index and/or the working tree, but never creates a new commit. After a succesful cherry-pick, the index and working tree will be exactly the same, and a new commit will have been created.

That said, the way changes are applied will be pretty much the same. Git needs some way to apply the changes from a specific commit to an arbitrary tree, and it makes no sense to use different implementations for `git stash` and `git cherry-pick`.